# Считывание выбранного элемента из XML (XDocument)

Tags: c#, xml

Какая команда в XDocument аналогична строке из xmlDocument: `pictureBoxItem1.ImageLocation = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ChildNodes[3].InnerText;`

Картина в общем: в combobox загружается поле Имя каждого элемента.С каждым выбором элемента в combox`e в элементы picturebox, textbox подставляются соответствующие строки выбранного элемента.И, не по теме, возможно ли сделать присвоение атрибута "id" автоматически?
Пример кода XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Champions>
 <Champion id="26">
  <NameC>NameHere</NameC>
  <ImageC>ImageLocation</ImageC>
  <BuildC>BuildHere</BuildC>
  <item1>ImageHere</item1>
   ....
  </Champion>
</Champions>
```

Вот код заполнения combobox

```
void FillComboBox()
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            var chmp = from Champion in
                           XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "champions.xml")).Descendants("Champion")
                       select new Champion
                       {
                           NameC = Champion.Element("NameC").Value.ToString()
                       };
            foreach (var Champion in chmp)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(Champion.NameC);
            }
```

Comment: Добавил.Атрибут у меня есть, просто реализация по нему потребует переделки кода.В комбобокс мне надо заполнять именно имя, а не ид.Можно, конечно, сделать и по атрибуту.Если вас не затруднит, и этот пункт сможете

Comment: Не затруднит, это как раз совсем просто для XDocument. Но вам нужно где-то помнить связь атрибутов и имен, так как имена имеют дурную привычку повторяться.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду переменную? Имена, кстати, и будут повторяться.Программа рассчитана на это.В файле может быть множество элементов с таким же именем.Пока с тем кодом, который у меня есть(из-за xmlDocument он большой, но рабочий), проблем нет.Но хотелось бы всё перевести на рельсы XDocument.Т.к. создание элемента у меня на XDocument, а вот считывание одно осталось на xmlDocument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идеальный вариант - создать нормальный модельный класс(ы), десериализовать XML в объекты и работать уже с объектами. Но если хочется извращений с голым XML, можно и так =)

`XDocument` и сопутствующие классы, в отличие от `XmlDocument`, возвращают `IEnumerable<T>` для коллекций вложенных элементов, LiNQ все таки. Поэтому прямого обращения по индексу там не предусмотрено. Можно выкрутиться путём материализации `IEnumerable<T>` в `List<T>`, но учтите, что в общем случае нет гарантии постоянного соответствия индексов и элементов.

Теперь о том как такого "монстра" сделать. Простой пример поиска элемента по `id` на примере вашего XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<Champions>"+
                            "<Champion id=\"25\">"+
                              "<NameC>NameHere</NameC>"+
                              "<ImageC>ImageLocation</ImageC>"+
                              "<BuildC>BuildHere</BuildC>"+
                              "<item1>ImageHere</item1>"+
                            "</Champion>"+
                          "</Champions>");

string id = "26";
string imageLocation = doc.Root.Elements
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == id)
    .Element("ImageC")?.Value);
```

Для автоматического заполнения `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`, можно использовать следующий код:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = doc.Root.Elements()
    .Select(e => new { Id = e.Attribute("id").Value, Name = e.Element("NameC").Value})
    .ToList();
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Теперь после выбора нужного элемента в `ComboBox`, свойство `ComboBox.SelectedValue` будет содержать значение атрибута `id`, которое нужно подставить в запрос выше. На этом все.

---

Еще раз повторю: да это **можно** сделать, но так делать **не нужно**. Лучше потратить немного времени на модельный класс(ы), настроить XML-сериализацию и работать в UI с коллекцией нормальных объектов и штатными биндингами.

Comment: Выглядит, конечно, красиво, но я не силён в компонентах работы с xml.Он у меня постольку-поскольку.Как переделать и десиреализовать, думаю, найду информацию как(было бы хорошо, если вы подскажите источники дельные).А вот как связать XDocument с изменением элемента в ComboBox я бы взглянул.

Comment: @Ricarnev дополнил ответ вариантом для WinForms. Добавьте соответствующую метку под вопрос, если вы строите UI на нем. Поп поводу сериализации, много примеров в документации на MSDN, ну и можете отдельный вопрос оформить, если что-то не получится.